# List.contains() returns true for object that violated hashCode contract

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hashcode

Having these entities:

*Review.java*:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Review {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String comment;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_book")
    private Book book;

    public Review() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Review review = (Review) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, review.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

*Book.java*:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    public Book() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, book.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

and finally *Main.java*:

```
public class Main {
    private static EntityManagerFactory getEmf(){
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h0");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManager em = getEmf().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Book b = em.find(Book.class, 1);

        Review r = new Review();
        r.setComment("This is a comment");
        r.setBook(b);

        //Object STATE 1
        //before the `r` is added, its r.getId() == `null`
        b.getReviews().add(r);

        //Object STATE 2
        //contract violation: now its r.getId() == `1`
        em.persist(r);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        em = getEmf().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        b = em.find(Book.class, 1);

        List<Review> reviews = b.getReviews();
        System.out.println(reviews.get(0).getBook().getTitle());

        //Object with STATE 2
        //yet the contains() method returns true even with changed id
        System.out.println(reviews.contains(r));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

output:

```
Some Book
true
```

How is it possible that `contains()` method of class `List` returns true when the state of its object (the Review `r`, which is using its `id` in hashCode calculation used for reading/writing into that collection) has changed? And thus the violation of the hashCode contract has occured?

Comment: `List.contains` uses `equals`, not `hashCode`.

Comment: How should it not be possible? Breaking a contract *may* lead to false results but does not *guarantee* false results.

Comment: Did I get the question? At the time of `reviews.contains(r)` I take your comments to mean that `r` has ID 1 and `reviews` contains a review from the database, presumably with ID 1. And now you’re asking how `contains()` can return `true`, is that it?

Comment: Also where is the broken hash code contract? I don’t see any.

Comment: @OleV.V. the `id` property, before statement `em.persist(r);` is `null`. After `persist` this will assign a value to that `id` (`1` , because it is the first, but that doesn't metter). So here -> the state has changed. The id changed from null to 1. The contract of object consistency (which the `hashCode() and Equals()` requires) has been broken.

Comment: Which contract are you referring to? I can’t remember that in my 23 years of Java programming I have read that an object must not change state in a way that changes the return values from `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Javadoc of [`List.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

So, it doesn't matter if `hashCode` is inconsistent with `equals`.

Granted, `Set.contains` has the same in its documentation, and there it does matter that `hashCode` is implemented consistently.

The difference arises in how the two are implemented: a `HashSet` uses the `hashCode` to work out "where to look" for the element, and thus may not find an element with an inconsistent hash code; a `List` such as an `ArrayList` will just linearly probe over all elements to find it, without bothering to check the hash code first.

Comment: Ok, so the attantion is about `equals()`, not `hashCode()` as I thought. But even then, the `equals()`  - if state of the underlaying object has changed - will return true? Because the state of the review has changed. So I assume the contract of consistency is the same for `hashCode()` and `equals()` as well. So that still should not return true